# $state, $stateParams, getting undefined object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, parameters

I am getting unexpected results from both methods.

I have my $state configed

```
    $stateProvider
                .state('status', {
                  url: "/status/:payment",
                  controller: 'QuestCtrl',
                  templateUrl: "index.html"
                });
```

And on the Controller I have:

```
    angular.module('quest').controller('QuestCtrl',function($scope,$stateParams,$state){

     console.log($stateParams.payment); // undefined

     console.log($state); // Object {params: Object, current: Object, $current: extend, transition: null}

}
```

I already used $stateParams in other projects and it worked but now I can't figure out what is going on here..

Comment: look at order you forgot $http :P ['$scope','$http', '$stateParams','$state',function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$state)

Comment: What's the URL in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: Guys, it is so embarrassed but I was trying to add $stateParams just to get an extra params so I forgot to add <ui-view> to my html. So now I am using the $location instead - simple. Sorry guys.. and thanks for the answers @jb-nizet, @ squiroid, @ thomas-weglinski

Answer (score 4):

```
        ['$scope','$stateParams','$state',
function($scope,  $http,          $stateParams, $state)
```

The names of the services don't match with the variables.

So $http is actually the $stateParams service, $stateParams is actually the $state service, and $state is undefined.

My advice: stop using this array notation, which clutters the code and is a frequent source of bugs. Instead, use ng-annotate as part of the build procedure, which will do it, correctly, for you.

Comment: @jb-zinet I will take a look on ng-annotate, thanks for the hint! although I fixed the order and I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Edit your question and add a section containing the new, updated code.

Answer (score 4):

As I already commented above You forgot to inject $http service

```
angular.module('quest').controller('QuestCtrl',
['$scope','$http','$stateParams','$state',function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$state){

 console.log($stateParams); // Empty Object
 console.log($stateParams.payment); // Empty Object

 console.log($state); // I get the entire state, I can see that my params are there.

console.log($state.params);
}
```

So your parameters mismatch and it turns out you will get $state in $stateparms and $state is empty.
And $http hold $state :P

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I fixed it the order but I am still getting the same result. 

I didn't know that the order matters on the Controllers since you're declaring it before.

Comment: Hey can you replicate it on plunker ?

Answer (score 2):

Missing parameter in routes.js

My example:

```
  .state('menu.cadastroDisplay', {
    url: '/page9',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/cadastroDisplay.html',
        controller: 'cadastroDisplayCtrl'
      }
    },
    params: { 'display': {} }
  })
```

Without this params in routes the $stateParams.yourParam always returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

With the ng-annotate library, the controller can be also initiated like this:

```
angular.module('quest')
    .controller('QuestCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$stateParams,$state) {

});
```

In this case you are avoiding problems with the injected objects ordering. Look at: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

If you are building your application with Grunt, use: `grunt-ng-annotate` package.

Answer (score 0):

Call   'ngInject' 
constructor($scope, $reactive, $stateParams, $state, $sce) {
    'ngInject'